# WSO2 API Manager - How to get User profile with consumer key & secrete

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Does anyone know how to get the user profile (including username & password) via rest API provided by wso2am with consumer key and secrete? 
Because we don't store username & password in client side but only consumer key and secrete, and generally, we have to provide 4 parameters (username,password,consumer key and consumer secrete) to get access token. so we want to use only consumer key and secrete to get access token.

Comment: Then you can the client credentials grant type to get the access token.https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Client+Credentials+Grant

Answer (score 0):

> // how to get the user profile (including username & password) via
>   rest API provided by wso2am//

AFAIK ,there is no such API defined at WSO2AM.To retrieve userprofiles,you have to call UserProfileMgtService , which is an admin  service.

Passwords are hashed and stored, so you cannot retrieve them. Username and password has to be provided by the user/client. You need to get that from the user request, and embed that with conusmer secret+id..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Our client is Mobile app, so that is why we don't want to store userid&password in mobile client. if username&password cracked, so anyone can logon store to un-scribe API, that is what We worried. Any suggestion for this situation?