# How to get user's profile in wso2 api manager?

Tags: javascript, node.js, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-data-services-server

I need get user's profile in wso2 api manager, how could i do that?
Until now, i've done get access token, refresh token and revoke token:

```
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token --> access and refresh token
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/revoke --> revoke token
```

Thanks for help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18394926/wso2-api-manager-how-to-get-user-profile-with-consumer-key-secrete

Comment: I need get user's name, last name, organization, email. Do you know how?, do you know the api or path? For example: the path to revoke token is https://localhost:9443/oauth2/revoke, which is the path to get user's profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you define openid as one of the scope, then you would be able to use userinfo endpoint to get the user related info.

Generate token with scope openid

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=openid" -H "Authorization: Basic NzhfQURZNGdBMWJ6djd0ZVc0Zk11VkpMM0xVYTpQWE55RmZ1ZjlmbkVhUW9NYksyaUxjTFE1dndh" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
```

use that token to request userinfo

```
curl -k  -H "Authorization: Bearer 14e78b764c91a1f18b5566ddbd88c5ff" https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid
```

by default, response would only contain the sub value.
{"sub":"admin@carbon.super"}

You can define which parameters you should send by configuring the claims in the service provide application in API Manager

for that log in to carbon management console and select the service provider application

under the claim configuration you can set email, lastname, and any other claims you need as 'Requested claims'

```
ex: http://wso2.org/claims/emailaddress for email
```

once configured, you would get following kind of response for previous request

```
{"sub":"admin@carbon.super","family_name":"adhikarinayake","email":"chamilaa@wso2.com"}
```

Comment: Thank you @Chamila. Also i saw this: http://localhost:9763/oauth2/?_wadl, there you can see the services token, revoke and userinfo.

Comment: i need in the response full_name, organization and email, i did what you told me, but the response not show that. What else can i do?